# JavaScript SQLite Html5

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I found a lot of documentation to create a local database (SQLite) in javascript and it works perfectly.
But now I want the database not to be created, but open directly from a directory, for example (C: \ Users ......).
Can I do it automatically?

This is the JavaScript to create the database

```
    var localDB = null;
    var CreateTb1 = "CREATE TABLE ......";
    var CreateTb2 = "CREATE TABLE ......";

    function onInit(){
    try {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            updateStatus("Erro: Seu navegador não permite banco de dados.");
        }
        else {
            initDB();
            createTables();
            //queryAndUpdateOverview();
        }
    } 
    catch (e) {
        if (e == 2) {
            updateStatus("Erro: Versão de banco de dados inválida.");
        }
        else {
            updateStatus("Erro: Erro desconhecido: " + e + ".");
        }
        return;
    }
}

    function initDB(){
    var shortName = 'database.db';
    var version = '1';
    var displayName = 'database.db';
    var maxSize = 65536; // Em bytes
    localDB = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
}

    function createTables(){

    localDB.transaction(function(transaction)
  {
    transaction.executeSql(CreateTb1, [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
    transaction.executeSql(CreateTb2, [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);

  }, tranonError, tranonSucc);


}
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript executed? In the browser? On the server side (like node,js)? Or in some runtime container like Cordova?

Comment: sorry in the Chrome browser with html5

Comment: Is this a normal website or are you writing a Chrome extension?

Comment: normal wbsite, no extension

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code running in a website in a browser cannot access files on the local drive of the user. That would be a huge security risk.

If you want a user to be able to use the data in a local file, you have to provide a mechanism for them to upload the file to your server where you can then access the data.

Note, that you cannot write back the data to the user's disk.